# OData JSON response from server comes back with line return characters

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

When you ask the OData server for JSON, the JSON response comes back with "\r\n" line returns.  Currently I'm stripping the response of the line returns on the client side.  Is there a way to have the JSON response come back without the "pretty format" without the "\r\n" line returns?

Response from server:

```
{\r\n"d" : [\r\n{\r\n"__metadata": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"\r\n}, "ID": 0, "Name": "Food", "Products": {\r\n"__deferred": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)/Products"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}, {\r\n"__metadata": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"\r\n}, "ID": 1, "Name": "Beverages", "Products": {\r\n"__deferred": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}, {\r\n"__metadata": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(2)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"\r\n}, "ID": 2, "Name": "Electronics", "Products": {\r\n"__deferred": {\r\n"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(2)/Products"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}
```

Expected response:

```
{"d" : [{"__metadata": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"}, "ID": 0, "Name": "Food", "Products": {"__deferred": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)/Products"}}}, {"__metadata": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"}, "ID": 1, "Name": "Beverages", "Products": {"__deferred": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products"}}}, {"__metadata": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(2)", "type": "ODataDemo.Category"}, "ID": 2, "Name": "Electronics", "Products": {"__deferred": {"uri": "http://services.odata.org/(S(cxfoyevtmm2e2elq52yherkc))/OData/OData.svc/Categories(2)/Products"}}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the last release. In the next release, we will fix the code to never indent the response payload. If the client